# which method is called when I back from a certain page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

let say I have 2 pages. Page A and Page B. from Page A, I move to Page B using

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("page B route name");
```

and then, from Page B, I tap the back button in the App Bar, so I go back to Page A.

Do I need to do something on Page A after back from Page B. which method in Page A is called in this situation?

in iOS native development, I usually use `viewWillAppear` method.

I have tried some lifecycles method below, but none of them is called as I want

```
 @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
     
    }
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
   
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant CreateEventCoordinatePage oldWidget) {
 
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I get it

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("page B route name").then((value) {
     print("Triggered after pop back in here");
});
```